# How can i read a file with multi headers?

Tags: r, input, io, read.table

I have a file with multiple headers and i also need the headers .

Head of my file :

```
>\>1 Len = 254

>13 112 1 18

>15 112 1 30

>22 11  3 25

>\>1 Reverse  Len = 254

>14 11 1 15

>\>2 Len = 186

>19 15 2 34

>25 11  3 25

>....
```

How can i read this file, and import the values into R variables (like dataframe)?

Alternatively, its good if someone could help we with removing the headers and adding another column that represents the number of table ( or shows this row is the first row of another table)

I don't want to read it as string and parse it

If it helps, the data is a report from MUMMER package

and also i uploaded an example here :
http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429271308686.txt

Comment: The usual approach is to load the file using `readLines` and then convert each line to character or numeric as desired.  Search SO a bit and you'll find several questions similar to yours.

Comment: Could you upload/ link to a shortened version of the actual datafile (.txt, .dat...) so we could have a go?

Comment: Basically you have to write your own parser if nobody has done that for this file format yet.

Comment: _"I don't want to read it as string and parse it"_ … welcome to the 80% of the time/work in data science/statistics.

Comment: @maxus i'v added the link blow my post, thanks

Comment: @hrbrmstr and i want to enjoy my 80% of time another way, and find the procedure and use it haha :))

Comment: `library(SOfun); read.mtable("http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429271308686.txt", ">")`? But that essentially reads the file in as a string and parses it. [Here's "SOfun"](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

Comment: Add a line to remove the "Reverse" values... `X <- read.mtable(URL, ">"); X <- X[!grepl("Reverse", names(X))]`. The result is a `list` of `data.frame`s.

Comment: Are the lines starting with ">" necessary? Would reading the file omitting the lines be ok or is the information from which block the data comes important?

Comment: @AnandaMahto thank you, is it windows binary or ubuntu source ? i'm using R under Ubuntu...

Comment: @ameerosein, if you have "devtools" installed, you can install it with `devtools::install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")`. Should work fine on Ubuntu--that's what I'm using most of the time.

Comment: @maxus the line's are starting with ">" necessarily and that lines are informative, just the number after ">" is informative so it is good if we can add another column storing just that number (or the number of ommiting lines before the corresponding row) and then ommiting that lines

Comment: @AnandaMahto thank you so much, i need to install devtools now, i'm new here, should i approve your answer as the right answer ?

Comment: Ah ok, otherwise I would have suggested x<-read.table("1429271308686.txt",comment.char=">")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I parse the data with a few lines of code and import the data into R

I merge all tables into one table and add a new column to represent the name 
of tables...

that's it :

```
lns = readLines("filename.txt") ; # read the data as character

idx = grepl(">", lns) ; # location of all ">"s

df = read.table(text=lns[!idx]) ; # read all lines as table unless those who starts with ">"

wd = diff(c(which(idx), length(idx) + 1)) - 1  ; # finding the index of each table to add in new column

df$label = rep(lns[idx], wd) ; # add table indices in a new column
```

and another way to do this special case is to use perl onliner that someone in other forum suggests me, I don't know what is it but it works :

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/66724/#66767

thanks others for their helpful answers and comments that helps me derive to write answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There is really no easy to do this without reading the whole thing in as a string and parsing it, but you can easily convert such actions into a function, as I have done with the `read.mtable` function in [my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

Here it is applied to your sample data:

```
## library(devtools)
## install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")

library(SOfun)
X <- read.mtable("http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429271308686.txt", ">")
X <- X[!grepl("Reverse", names(X))]

names(X)
#  [1] "> 1  Len = 354"   "> 2  Len = 127"   "> 3  Len = 109"   "> 4  Len = 52"   
#  [5] "> 5  Len = 1189"  "> 6  Len = 1007"  "> 7  Len = 918"   "> 10  Len = 192" 
#  [9] "> 11  Len = 169"  "> 13  Len = 248"  "> 14  Len = 2500"
X[1]
# $`> 1  Len = 354`
#        V1  V2  V3  V4
# 1  203757   1   1  35
# 2  122132   1   1  87
# 3  203756   1   1 354
# 4       1   1   1 354
# 5   42364  12   1  89
# 6  203757  37  37  91
# 7  122132  90  90  38
# 8   42364 102  91  37
# 9  203757 129 129 168
# 10  42364 140 129 212
# 11 122132 129 129 212
# 12 203757 298 298  43
```

As you can see, it has created a `list` of 11 `data.frame`s, each named with the "Len =" value.

The two arguments used here are the file location (here a URL) and the `chunkID`, which can be set to a regular expression or a fixed pattern that you want to match. Here, we want to match any lines that start with a ">" as indicative of where a new dataset starts.

Comment: is there any constraints on length of the file or on other things ?
i apply the function for my example file that is a fraction of my file and it works properly, but when i use it for the original file it goes wrong and says:
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 6 elements

Comment: @ameerosein, There shouldn't be a file length restriction. The error you mention is related to the fact that `read.table` isn't able to guess your columns correctly. Is a space the only delimiter?

Comment: yeah...
as you see in the message, it is about the second line... second line of my example and original file are the same... i copied starting lines as example..
so the only difference is the size of the files...

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want a long winded cumbersome method...

```
# if you just want the data and not the header information

x<-read.table("1429271308686.txt",comment.char=">")

# in case all else fails, my somewhat cumbersome solution...
x<-scan("1429271308686.txt",what="raw")

# extract the lengths, ind1 has all the lengths
ind1<-x=="="
ind1<-c(ind1[length(ind1)],ind1[-length(ind1)]) # take the value that comes after "="
cumsum(ind1)
lengths<-as.numeric(x[ind1])[c(TRUE,FALSE)] # only want one of the lengths

# remove the unwanted characters
ind2<-x==">"
ind2<-c(ind2[length(ind2)],ind2[-length(ind2)]) # take the value that comes after ">"

ind3<-x==">"|x=="Len"|x=="="|x=="Reverse"
dat<-as.numeric(x[!(ind1|ind2|ind3)]) # remove the unwanted

# arrange as matrix
mat<-matrix(dat,length(dat)/4,4,byrow=T)

# the number of rows for each block
block<-(c(1:length(x))[duplicated(cumsum(!ind2))][c(FALSE,TRUE)]-c(1:length(x))[duplicated(cumsum(!ind2))][c(TRUE,FALSE)]-5)/4

# the number for each block
id<-as.numeric(x[ind2])[c(TRUE,FALSE)]

# new vector
mat<-cbind(rep(id,block),mat) # note, this assumes that the last line is again "> Reverse"
```

Comment: thank you but there's a problem ! we also need the Reverse tables, in the example that i've been uploaded all the reverse tables are empty but some of them have records ! i update the little example in my question, take a look please

Comment: and the second problem is that if any Reverse table is not empty then all the indices will goes wrong from that place to the end ...